# All browsers are failing to open any web pages

Tags: applications, browser

I have a Galaxy S5 with Android 5.1.1. My phone is rooted, and has been working fine since I updated about a month ago. Within the last few days, I have been having this issue, and I don't know what change might have brought it about.

My preferred browser is Firefox, but I also have the default browser and Chrome installed. Regardless of which of them I use, when I open them, they just give me a white screen. Eventually I just get the message that says I can make the app stop, or wait for a response.

All other internet connecting apps work fine. Twitter, Instagram, Facebook messenger... it is strictly *only* browsers that are not working.

What is strange to me is that it is more than one browser that is failing. If just Firefox, or just Chrome, was failing, then I would assume the apps themselves were broken. But it's all three browsers failing the exact same way.

This happens whether I'm on wifi or mobile service. I've tried restarting the phone, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the apps, as well as clearing cache and data.

Is there some system resource common to all of them? Is there some plausible explanation for why all browsers would fail? And, of course, if there's a solution that can get them all working again, that would be great.

Comment: @Questioner - Have you tried others like Opera, UC, Dolphin? Are they working?